# Access the live website while the domain used for virtual hosts locally

Tags: php, apache

Let's say, i set the name-based virtual host for my working project in D:/xampp/htdocs/myproject with [myproject.com](http://www.myproject.com). It runs well locally.

Then, i buy the domain name with exactly match with virtual domain : [myproject.com](http://www.myproject.com) and i want to access the live domain instead of virtual domain in the same computer while the apache is running.

Are there any ways to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this computer accessible from the external Internet?

Comment: no because how will the browser know what IP to use

Comment: Sure there is. It all boils down to getting the name resolution right. You have to implement some form of switch. Typically you add a line into your local `/etc/hosts` file for local testing or comment it out when not required. A better approach though is to use a _modified_ domain name locally, something like `my.great.domain.local`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the host file and remove such as  127.0.0.1 myproject.com.
So you can visit myproject.com via DNS.